# What is the best way to open an imported javascript source file using VS Code Extension API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm attempting to write a VS Code extension for React. The basic gist is, I want to select a React Component and Open/goto the source of the component function/class and do some operations there.

In case the source is in another file, what is the best(and most reliable) way to open the file and do operations to it using the VS Code Extension API?

I have used the ast of the document to retrieve the relative import file source from a component and can access the required file that way, but what if the user is using import aliases or Import Path Resolver to import components like this.

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
import Grid from 'components/Grid';
```

instead of

```
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Grid from '../../components/Grid';
```

I know VS code has a peek feature so it definitely has file source information somewhere. What is the best way to open an imported javascript source file using VS Code Extension API?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @imiro I had to abandon this project. Will pick it up soon and will share the solution if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  `"moduleNameMapper": {...}` to be used in the `package.json` file.